# When adding a column the column appears in parent folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, document-library, column, folder

I have created a Content Type called "Contracts Folder" where I have created some columns like "Contract Start Date" and "Contract End Date". I have a parent folder called "Contracting and Procurement" where the Content Type is "Folder". Under this folder I have a folder called "Contracts" where the Content Type is "Folder" as well. All folders in the "Contracts" folder are Content Type "Contracts Folder".

I want to show the columns I created under the Content Type "Contract Folder" in the "Contracts" folder. I do this by pressing "+Add column" then "Show or hide columns". I select them from the list and the columns are now visible in the "Contracts" folder which was the intention so I am happy.

What bothers me is that they also appear in the parent folder "Contracting and Procurement" and sister folders as well. it is as if I can only apply the view for "Contracting and Procurement" and all all of its sub-folders. How can I show the columns in only a sub-folder like the "Contracts" folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how SharePoint document libraries work. When you add a column in document library *view*, it is added at library level & not folder/subfolder/file level.

So, if you change any library view settings (like adding/removing columns or grouping/filters/sorting), change will be applied at document library(view) level & not folder/subfolder/file level.

There is no SharePoint out of the box way to show/hide the column for particular content types (folders/subfolders/files).

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply. So if I understand it correct, my view will apply to all folders and sub-folders in the library? I thought that by choosing different Content Types I could chose different views. Do I need to make libraries for each different view?

Comment: Yes, views are created at library level hence they will be applied to all folders and subfolders. If you want you can create additional views in document library. However, whichever column you are showing in "a view" will be shown for all folders & subfolders inside that view irrespective of it's content type.